# React UseEffect infinite loop due to calling a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop, react-context

I'm using the ContextAPI for user login in my application, and I created a hook that will call the currently logged in user so that I can show/hide login buttons etc in components.

In the useEffect function of the component where I need this data, I call the function as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    authContext.getAuth()
    
  }, []);
```

The function is contained in the auth-context.tsx file as follows:

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react';

interface LoginCredentials {
  username: string | undefined;
  password: string | undefined;
}

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  loading: false,
  login: (login: LoginCredentials) => {},
  getAuth: () => {},
  error: '',
  loggedInUser: null,
});

interface AuthContextProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const AuthContextProvider = (props: AuthContextProviderProps) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>('');
  const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState(null);

/* THIS FUNCTION BEING CALLED */
  const getAuthUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/v1/users/getuser');

    if (response.status === 500) {
      setError('Server Error! Please try again soon...');
      setLoading(false);
    }

    const userData = await response.json();
    console.log(userData)

    if (userData.message) {
      setError(userData.message);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setLoggedInUser(userData.data.user); /* THIS LINE IS CAUSING LOOP */
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        login: loginHandler,
        getAuth: getAuthUser,
        loading: loading,
        error: error,
        loggedInUser: loggedInUser,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

The line marked above where I am setting the loggedInUser causes a infinite loop when I pass an object, in this case the returned object from userData.data.user, but works ok when I pass a string from this object, such as userData.data.user.username. It actually works ok for what I need, but in future versions I will need to pass an object. I am guessing it has something to do with primitive vs reference types, but would be grateful if someone could explain why a string works but not an object, and what I would need to fix, thanks!

I removed authContext from dependancy array of useEffect in calling component, fixes the issue but getting a warning that the array should not be empty, is it bad to have this warning?

Comment: Can you post your whole useEffect?

Comment: `object != object == true` in js, so probably u attach object as effect dependency in the use case and therefore the shallow compare between renders runs the effect again, add the useeffect usage that runs the function

Comment: Wrap the context `value` inside a `useMemo` and the `getAuthUser` in a `useCallback`